# AlwaysOn Primary Showing as Question Mark

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

If I look in the dashboard for my AlwaysOn implementation I can see my groups are synchronised and no data loss.  They also failover successfully but when looking in the Group folder list under replicas on the secondary, the primary node is showing as having a question mark next to it.

Has anyone seen that before?

[image]

Comment: Can you refresh and post a screenshot ? What version of SSMS are you using - use the latest 2014?

Answer (score 2):

That is normal. It is just indicates you that you are on the secondary server and the role is taking care of by the primary node (the one without the question mark). If it was a 3 node or more cluster you might see the question mark on all node expect the primary. When it failover you will see the reciprocal of this on the other server.